# How can I make my external jquery file work as I intend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

on page load, the parent div of copyright should change in width and center. this div on every page does not have an ID or class for some reason.
So I am using this code below in a javascript file that is linked at the top of my page

```
(function(){
    $("#copyright").parent().css({
      'margin-left':'auto',
      'margin-right':'auto',
      'width':'900px'
    });
})();
```

but I see no results. However, when I post this into the google chrome console log, the desired effect happens, which is the centering of the DIV.

Why is this not working in my external file?

Comment: Depends largely on everything else in your external file

Comment: Is the jQuery loaded above the #copyright element? If so your jQuery is executing before the DOM element you are selecting exists and as a result the css isn't applied. If this is the case you can either use @comFreek's answer below (which will wait to execute until the DOM is loaded) or load your jQuery below the markup that defines #copyright.

Comment: Can't you edit the HTML?

Comment: @Jonathan yes i could but then I would need to do that on every page

Comment: If you use NP++ you can edit all pages at once. CTRL+H -> replace in all documents. Visual Studio can do this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a dollar sign and there is a pair of superfluous parentheses at the end.

```
$(function(){
    $("#copyright").parent().css({
      'margin-left':'auto','margin-right':'auto','width':'900px'
    });
});
```

Without the dollar sign, you are calling the function before the page has even loaded*. That can't work.

*) assuming you didn't put the script block before `</body>`.

Comment: this code $(function(){
 $("#copyright").parent().css({
 'margin-left':'auto','margin-right':'auto','width':'900px'
 });
 })(); still doesn't work onload

Comment: for a different file but not for the one im using

Comment: Please verify that `console.log($("#copyright").parent());` (appended to your current code) outputs the right element.

Comment: it returns TypeError: object is not a function

Answer (score 0):

you need to be sure the parent container is "drawn" before trying to center the panel, so you should call this on a

```
$(document).ready(function() { yourFunction });
```